# Stackoverflow exception over WCF (while manually it simply works)

Tags: wcf, serialization, datacontract

I am experiencing this weirdest problem ever.
I have EF entities that we are passing between a client and a server via WCF.

When i am serializing them manually as follows:

```
        var xmlSerializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(T), null, int.MaxValue, false, true, null);
        var textWriter = new StringWriter();
        var xmlTextWriter = new XmlTextWriter(textWriter);
        xmlSerializer.WriteObject(xmlTextWriter, source);
        return textWriter.ToString();
```

Everything is ok.
But when they are being transferred over the wcf wire i get stackoverflow exception.

I tried debugging the source code, but since it is stackoverflow all the locals are unavailable.

I ran out of ideas, if it serializes manually - what could be different in the WCF that would cause it to stackoverflow?

Comment: When you use EF or Linq to SQL, you may be hitting a recursive property, for examlple Account -> Address -> Account -> Address. Ignoring the Account property in the Address class may help in that case.